# Can I force application to cleanup/reduce memory usage to a task(task manager,exe)

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, ram

I want to create an binary exe that "cleans or reduces," for lack of a better term of another process which is a binary(exe).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? How will an external process know more than the process itself about how to reduce its use of RAM?

Comment: You never asked a question. Also, why do you want to? Unused ram is wasted ram. It is like paying people to do work but you order everyone to go to a break room across town when they are not actively doing something. The best you can do if you really wanted to do this is force a GC using profiling apis.

Comment: No i don't think you can do this, this is part responsibility operating system and how it works, and part the responsibility of the application and/or framework memory manager it uses. you cant just aggressively tell the operating system or application/framework to do this as far as i know

Comment: The binary exe becomes unstable and eventually crashes  once it gets to about ~1500 memory. I am curious if there is a way to "reverse engineer" my way into it.

Comment: I found this tool. github/JordanZaerr/GarbageCollector it's giving me runtime error System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'EasyHook64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)' I referenced it.